# Drop-down list based on value on another cell in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

[image]

I have searched for this question and found some useful tips but I can't seem to figure out the answers that they provide, so here's the scenario:

- Top image: Sheet Name is Animals
- Bottom Image: Sheet Name is Health

So the sheet Animals Column A (Owner) contains the data for dropdown list in sheet Health Column A (Owner).

What I want is in sheet Health if I choose CoopB (on dropdownlist Based on sheet Animals) I want the Column B (ETN) row 2 to become dropdownlist and the choices is based on the value of CoopB in sheet Animals.

Example: On sheet Health

```
| Column A (Owner) | ColumnB(ETN) |
|------------------|--------------|
| CoopB            | CW-011110    |
| CoopC            | CC-111101    |
| Coop1            | Coop1-0001   |
```

Note: on Sheet Animals Column C (Owner) value can be repeated, for example, we can expect `CoopB` value to appear repeatedly but on Column D (ETN) data are unique.

Comment: My [answer to your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267085/data-validation-cell-lock-if-value-is-true-google-spreadsheet/39321765#39321765) applies here as well. Did you try adapting that?

Comment: @JMA if you don't correctly respond/close your previous questions no one will want to answer the new questions

Comment: @Robin - okay let me make this clear, the previous question is different from this question, this question refers more on dependent dropdownlist, the previous question refers on locking cells based on data value from another sheet,

Comment: @Harold, sorry for my late response on previous questions, will not do again. thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You can work similarly here, this time a Control sheet seems like a little less overkill.

- Let's create a sheet called `Control`
- In `Control!A1` put `"Owner"`
- In `Control!A2` put `=UNIQUE(Animals!C2:C)`
- In the data validation of `Health!A2:A` put the range `Animals!A2:A`

Now you can select the unique pet owners.

## For a single Owner

For a single owner (in `Health!A2`) you could

- In `Control!B1` put `"ETN"`
- In `Control!B2` put `FILTER(Animals!D2:D, Animals!C2:C = Health!A2)`

## For multiple Owners

For multiple owners we need to use the control sheet some more

- In `Control!B2` put `=Health!A2:A` so we have a mirror of our selections in `Health`
- In `Control!C2` put `=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Animals!D2:D, Animals!C2:C = B2)), "")`.
- Drag the formula down however far you think you may need it (I could not get this to work with an Array formula)
- Set the data validation in `Animals!B2` to `Control!C2:Z2`, in `Animals!B3` to `Control!C3:Z3` etc.

  - [You have to do this manually unless you want to write a script that fills in the data validation rules for you](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/VdI6SGKLDic)